# List webpart grouping expands at auto-refresh

Tags: 2013, list-view, grouping, data-refresh

I am using a webpart that displays a view of a list, that uses grouping and auto-refresh (ajax) with 15 seconds interval.
If I collapse the grouping, when it refreshes it automatically un-collapses it.

I guess that with each refresh, it falls back to thr default collapse state, which in this case is un-collapsed.

Is there any way to keep the auto refresh AND the collapse state with each update?

Comment: Make sure your view setting has "Keep Collapsed" as an option.

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha The thing is, I want to keep its previous state. If it was collapsed I want it to remain collapsed. If it wasn't collapsed, I want it to remain uncollapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your ajax refresh and add a CEWP with the following code.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15;url=pageurl">
```

Replace "pageurl" with your actual url.

Comment: I dont want a full postback to the server (although after microsoft introduced updatepanel I no longer trust in the ajax capabilities of microsoft), I wish only the content of thr specific wp to update. Tl;dr: I don't want a white screen and a full page refresh

Comment: Makes sense. Having only the web part update is ideal situation but for whatever reason it doesn't play nice with Groupings...

Comment: Maybe there is a way I can invoke the callback of the native ajax update? I'm guessing a function can be found in one of the js sp objects

Comment: @SharonJDDorot Can you enable Manual refresh for the web part, and check to see if clicking the refresh button removes the grouping?

Comment: it acts the same, resets the collapsed state to its default state

Comment: bummer, i guess its a Microsoft ajax issue than. Maybe look into this http://scenicsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/11/using-javascript-to-asynchronously.html

Comment: it seems like a nice work-around, i'll give it a shot although I think itll do the same. By calling __dopostback you essentially reload the control, reverting all the "custom settings" (eg collapsed state) to it's default. Guess it's just not natively possible. Maybe i'll end up with a custom wp that uses rest. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yea I think that is a better option. Sucks that OOB functionality is limited.